# Using one xcdatamodelId in two app

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I created one project with core data that will work with unchangeable database. And I don't want to write code in this project , that will programmatically populate this database. So, I create second project with core data, add existing xcdatamodel from first project without copying(only references). There i populate my database, open it with mozilla plug-in and it successfully filled. Then I copy ,my *.sqlite file and manually replace it with old file in first project. It causes error:"The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store". But I use for both files the same xcdatamodelid. Where my error?

Sorry for my english, I really need help.

P.S. when I open sqlite file from first project and second (with commented code of populate base) in FileMerge - second is already empty. I appreciate any advice or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karoly S nicely answers the question. I have a hint that I frequently employ that may prevent this out of sync situation. Instead of two Xcode projects trying to share one model file, just create one Xcode project with two targets. Each target will use the same model file, any class definitions derived from that model, and possibly other code. My second target is a Mac OS command line program that generates the database, while my first target continues to be the iOS app that reads that database. The Mac OS target will overwrite the database file in a project subdirectory, ensuring it's up-to-date. If I make any changes to the model, Xcode knows to update both targets.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change your Model Definitions in any way? The error you are seeing is because there is some difference between the model from when you created it, and again from when you are trying to reference it. Are you running on the simulator? Try to delete both of your apps to clear the data related to it, as it might be out of date. Afterwards simply rebuild both of your projects as that will update your core data database.

EDIT: To clarify a bit more, your core data model is out of sync, this is generally caused by you building and running an app, and a database being created, then redefining your object model, this can be done in a variety of ways, most likely caused by the addition of an attribute or entity. So when you are trying to load the database there are fields that the app and core data are looking for, but are not there because they did not exist when the database was created. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer.Step by step:I create empty database in my main project.Then I create in InitializeDataBase project database(only create,without any data).After that,I copy this *.sqlite file to folder with main.sqlite(database names is the same) and replace old one with new.So,I don't change anything in xcdatamodel,but the problem remains.And one interesting fact-when I compare both *.sqlite files in FilesMerge utility,the first one,from main proj not empty-it has desription of tables,in contrast with sqlite file from second proj,which is empty.Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Hmm... So you do replace the actual created database that is reference by your app? Is there any chance you could give us the exact error message you are getting?